# Riemann surface of $K_0(z)$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, bessel-functions

The question concerns the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order zero ($K_0(z)$).

How does its Riemann surface looks like? How can one evaluate its values on the "other" sheet(s)?

Comment: It is of the form $g(z)\log z$, where $g$ is entire (has explicit power series), which answers all your questions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I believe this is not true (see the 1-st eq. at http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/06/01/04/01/02/ ). However, $z=0$ is a logarithmic branch point.

Comment: Sorry, it is of the form $g(z)\log z+h(z)$ where $g$ and $h$ are entire functions, which answers all your questions.